# Can't define a term in Python

Tags: python, numpy

First post so I'll try to be specific as possible.

I'm trying to define a term `ybar1` in Python. I'm intending for `ybar1` to be the average of a list `y1`

```
where y1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

What I'm doing first is:

```
import numpy as np
```

then defining a new function

```
def funk(y1):
     print np.sum(y1)/len(y1)
     return;
```

So now when I compute `funk(y1)` I get a number, 3

Now is where it gets weird. I try to say:

```
ybar1 = funk(y1)
```

, which returns the value 3

but then when I type `ybar1` alone, I get no output.

Thoughts?

Comment: Please reedit your question by indenting the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
def funk(y1):
  return np.sum(y1)/len(y1)
```

You were not actually *returning* a value from the function, only printing a result on the console. Also, there's a better way to compute the average using `numpy`:

```
def funk(y1):
  return np.mean(y1)
```